# Word for "completely fascinated"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is a word for *completely fascinated*? I want to convey the same meaning but using only one word if possible. Using two big words for this seems like an overkill.

Comment: I like Claire's suggestions, and arik-so's *mesmerised* and *captivated*; I'm less convinced by *intrigued* as to me it signifies mere piquing of curiousity rather than fascination, and by *engrossed* as it is closer to being very involved in a task than fascination with a subject.

Comment: Agreed *intriguing* is more about piquing curiousity than mesmerising/captivating, but *engrossing* doesn't have to involve active participation in a task. In fact, *mesmerising / mesmerizing* doesn't occur that often in relation to films / movies, but *engrossing* is actually [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=engrossing+film%2Ccaptivating+film&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) than *captivating* in this context.

Comment: Substitute "an activity" for "a task" and I would say my assertion holds - *engrossing* has more to do with holding your full attention than provoking interest/fascination. The fact that it's more commonly used than *captivating* in the context of films is not particularly relevant - a film can be both captivating and engrossing without redundancy.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you could use a thesaurus to look up synonyms for *fascinated*.

Comment: Completely fascinated as opposed to partially fascinated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

entranced! enthralled! enchanted!

Answer (score 6):

I might go with ***engrossed***.

Comment: My rule of thumb is that a movie must be *engrossing* if it's longer than, say, two hours, and I don't notice this unless I check my watch or have some other reminder of the passage of time (my brain likes engrossing movies, but my bladder doesn't! :)

Comment: I can only assume the downvoter doesn't have a dictionary. :)

Comment: Or agrees with @Graham Snyder that to be *engrossed* in something implies you must in some way be an "active" participant in whatever it is (which I don't think is the case).

Answer (score 4):

*Smitten* can be used, I think.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

Amazed, captivated, intrigued, mesmerized, (maybe awestruck, might be applicable in some cases)?

Answer (score 1):

I like arik-so's *intrigued*. Alternatively, I suggest *enthralled*.

Answer (score 1):

*[Enraptured](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enrapture)* must be mentioned, to accompany "*entranced*! *enthralled*! *enchanted*!" and *engrossed*.
*Enrapture* means "to fill with great delight or joy; to fascinate."